# Create Antd Tree based on checked Node of another Antd Tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, antd

I want to create a Tree antd data with only checked nodes of another Tree data, please take a look here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzHSm.png)

When I Check some nodes and click on validate, I want to be able to filter only checked/half checked data from my data and create another Tree with new data.
This is my sandbox, please take a look :)
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-browser-glh4n?file=/index.js

Example with images : When i check this node and i click on validate : [image when I select nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zqcs.png) , I expect to get this result : [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6XYm.png)
Thank you

Comment: could you please show me the result tree with an example ? if checked node was from two sub tree what would be the shape of final new tree?

Comment: Hi, i edit my post, please take a look :)

Comment: The last node '0-2' is not 'checked' - still it needs to be on the new-tree, correct?

Comment: No, only the checked ones, i forgot the delete it sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a recursive method to create new tree data based on checked and half checked tree nodes, actually it filters the original tree with it's sub tree.

here's the updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-moser-fhuuk?file=/index.js) :

```
const createNewTreeData = (treeData, checkedKeys) => {
  return treeData.reduce((acc, treeDataItem) => {
    if (checkedKeys.includes(treeDataItem.key)) {
      if (treeDataItem.children) {
        acc.push({
          ...treeDataItem,
          children: createNewTreeData(treeDataItem.children, checkedKeys)
        });
      } else {
        acc.push(treeDataItem);
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
};
```

And in onCheck event I've added halfchecked nodes to allChecked state like this:

```
onCheck = (checkedKeys, e) => {
    const allCheckedKeys = [...checkedKeys, ...e.halfCheckedKeys];
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      allCheckedKeys,
      checkedKeys
    }));
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for, thank you!
 I have another question please, who can i persist checked nodes after refreshing ? I have tried with defaultCheckedKeys but it not working..

Comment: I think you can initialze checkedKeys with some values like ["0-0"] in component state and at first time the component render with initial checkedKeys

Comment: Yes! But the problem is the halfChecked nodes, how can i Check the checked ones and halfCheck the halfcheclked nodes before refreshing?

Comment: as the antd doc says you can either use the string[] or  {checked: string[], halfChecked: string[]} for checked keys to include half checked keys

Comment: Hi @HDM91, I want to disable checking childs on my TreeData ,but when parent is checked all his childs get printed in the created Tree, have you an idea how to solve it please ?
Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-haibt-hjo4kf